# First Delphi IDE that supports 64-bit development

Tags: delphi, ide, 64-bit

What is the first Delphi IDE that supports 64-bit application development? I want to convert my projects from 32-bit to 64-bit.

Comment: Why don't you get the latest? Should be more easy to get than an old copy. And if you want it for free, get the community edition, which is a full Professional edition but with a limiting license. If your projects are not commercial, that shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 64 bit Windows compiler was introduced in XE2.